# show logout button along with the name of user after successfull login

Tags: yii, authentication, header, logout

I am a yiibie, and i am stuck at a point. I have three roles in my project. 1.Admin. 2.Owner 3. Authenticated User. I have a header and a footer widget.In header widget which is the top section has a signup and login link. i want to show my user name and a logout link after his successful login. I do not want to make another widget. i Know the logic, we can use if else.
If a user has been logged in, show his name and logout link at the top section(header widget). else if he is a normal user or not logged in show him, signup and login link. Thats it.But how to write code..is the thing i dont know. Plus i am using yii rights and yii user extension too.

Comment: What did you try to write and what problems have you got?

Comment: <?php if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){?>
 <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/user/registration">Sign up</a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/user/login">login</a></li>
<?php }?>
 <?php if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){?>
<li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/user/logout">(<?php echo Yii::app()->user->name ?>) &nbsp;logout</a></li>
done with the solution

Comment: Please add the code to the original post. No one in their right mind is going to try and work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation please.

This will be helpful:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#isGuest-detail

Here example: http://pastebin.com/r0XpkPNZ

Comment: but how can i echo the name of the current user. and this is only for guest..... what about the roles ??? admin, owner and authenticated user.

Comment: Somethink like that: <?php echo Yii::app()->user->name;?>

Answer (score 1):

Is easy after login you can see the username otherwise you see nothings

```
<?php  
   if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    echo Yii::app()->user->name;
   }
 ?>
```