# Directing user to the desired page

Tags: php, authentication, yii

i have installed yii user and rights and upon login through "webapp/user/login" it directs me to the index.php page.
i want to direct admin to another page rather then index.php page.
which file would i need to edit to direct admin to the desired page. Help needed.

Comment: show site controller.  where you have the action login

Comment: I have posted an answer in the code there are comment for explai where redirect  or render to the page you want.

Comment: i am using yii user and right extension. well upon login i from the url "webapp/user/login" i want to go the page webapp/story/create. how can i write this in the code you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have this code in you site/controller

```
/**
 * Displays the login page
 */
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {   
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
           // 
           //this if you want redirect to returnUrl (index.php by default) 
           // here you can change redirect to url you prefer 
           // or render proper page  
           // $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
           // this for your destination 
            $this->redirect(array('story/create'));
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Comment: i am using yii user and right extension. well upon login i from the url "webapp/user/login" i want to go the page webapp/story/create. 
how can i write this in the code you have mentioned above.

Comment: mate it isn't redirecting me from "webapp/user/login" to "webapp/stroy/create"
instead of this from "webapp/site/login" it is redirecting me to "webapp/story/create"

Comment: please make sure that i am using yii user and right extension..!!

Comment: I don't understand you goal please explain better. I think you after login want go to story/create ...

Comment: i guess i am confusing between site/login and user/login
i guess both are the same things, am i right..??

Comment: The login is  One only.  Site login is the controller for this action. But you can check.

Comment: For check go to the layout (main.php in view/layout) you can see the controller/action call by login.

Comment: i have another ques. this is the link, please try to answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272633/show-logout-button-along-with-the-name-of-user-after-successfull-login

Comment: I have answered to the link above but is not you question...right?

Comment: oh sorry, i gave u the wrong link, here is the correct one..!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597530/yii-upon-login-show-the-username-and-logout-button
the link before was just for reference.

Comment: hi @scaisEdge, can you please help me with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610115/yii-redirecting-the-admin-and-authenticated-user-to-the-desired-page

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge, can u please look into this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639931/yii-the-system-is-unable-to-find-the-requested-action-select