# Yii redirecting the admin and authenticated user to the desired page

Tags: yii

I am new to yii. I want my admin upon login from webapp/user/login to redirect to the page I want which is localhost/webapp/story right now it is redirecting me to the index.php.

I have also registered a user and given that user a role which is authenticated and I want that when my user(the authenticated user) logs in via webapp/user/login then that user is redirected to index.php.

so there are two things:

```
1. redirecting admin to the desired page which is webapp/story.
2. redirecting the authenticated user to index.php.
```

I am using yii user and right extension. Please help me with this. 
The code LoginController is below:

```
<?php

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public $defaultAction = 'login';

    /**
     * Displays the login page
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        $model=new UserLogin;
        // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['UserLogin']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['UserLogin'];
            // validate user input and redirect to previous page if valid
            if($model->validate()) {
                $this->lastViset();
                if (Yii::app()->user->returnUrl=='/index.php')
                        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);
                else// yehen par kuch aye ga according
                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('/user/login',array('model'=>$model));
        } else
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);
     }

    private function lastViset() {
    $lastVisit =     User::model()->notsafe()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $lastVisit->lastvisit = time();
    $lastVisit->save();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think could be somethings like this

```
<?php

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public $defaultAction = 'login';

    /**
     * Displays the login page
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        $model=new UserLogin;
        // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['UserLogin']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['UserLogin'];
            // validate user input and redirect to previous page if valid
            if($model->validate()) {

                $this->lastViset();

                // Old code commentede
                //if (Yii::app()->user->returnUrl=='/index.php')
                //        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);
                //else// yehen par kuch aye ga according
                //    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);

                // new code
                if (UserModule::isAdmin()){
                    $this->redirect(array('story/index'));
                }  
                else  {
                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);   
                }  


            }
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('/user/login',array('model'=>$model));
        } else
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);
     }

    private function lastViset() {
    $lastVisit =     User::model()->notsafe()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $lastVisit->lastvisit = time();
    $lastVisit->save();
    }

 }
```

Comment: i really appreciate but i had mentioned the wrong url in the question and im sorry for that. the correct url is "webapp/user/login". i think changes will be made in the LoginController.php which is in the user extension.
 i have updated the question.. please see the code upthere and i have also updated the question...!!

Comment: the code you showed now is the one you want modify?

Comment: yes mate, a friend of mine told me that you have to make changes in there for the things you want.

Comment: thanks mate,i will check... actually the work i am trying to do is to get the roles of the registered users. 
Like if the user is admin, then upon login the admin should see the sidebarwidget as i have created the sidebar widget and if the user(authenticated) gets logged in it just see's the index.php..!!
i hope u understand.

Comment: please have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617055/getting-roles-of-registered-users

Comment: please help me with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631514/yii-error-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by