# Yii: The system is unable to find the requested action "select"

Tags: yii, jquery-select2

what i am doing is trying using the yii select2 extension to create a searchable dropdown list. i have downloaded the extension from this link and following it "http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/".
i have put the unzipped file(which is select2) in protected/extensions and i have then created a php file in "protected/views/site/select.php" in which i pasted the code below and when i try to run it via "webapp/index.php/site/login" it gives this error "
Error 404
The system is unable to find the requested action "select"." Please help me with this, thankyou..!!

```
 //code in select.php(protected/views/site/select.php)
$tags=array('Satu','Dua','Tiga');
echo CHtml::textField('test','',array('id'=>'test'));
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
'selector'=>'#test',
'options'=>array(
'tags'=>$tags,
),
));
```

Comment: Have you add in your main.php file the following: 'import'=>array(
        ...
        'application.components.*',
),

Comment: yes i have this im my config/main.php file

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis can you please look into this..?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754332/yii-video-upload-gets-failed-upon-uploading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have make the view file (`protected/views/site/select.php)` but you don't have created the corresponding action.

Add in `SiteController`:

```
public function accessRules() {
    //You can modify accordingly but you have to insert select to allowable actions
   return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index', 'contact' and 'select' actions
            'actions'=>array('index', 'contact', 'select'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}

 public function actionSelect() {
    $this->render('select');
}
```

Comment: yes mate thanks it works, can you explain briefly what was the problem..??

Comment: The error " The system is unable to find the requested action "select". " means that you had to make the action "select" in your controller.

Comment: I 'm glad that i helped you.

Comment: bro url is working but the field isn't working, i mean when i type "Satu" or the name in the above mentioned code.. it isn't giving me the dropdown list...

Comment: Give me a minute to check it.

Comment: hmmmm, what could be the problem..!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94763/discussion-between-kostas-mitsarakis-and-salik-asad).

Comment: @Kotas Mitsarakis please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658872/yii-why-my-default-index-of-controller-is-not-working

Comment: hi @Kotas Mitsarakis please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709492/property-tablename-title-is-not-defined