# Yii: why my default index of controller is not working?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, rights

I am a Yiibie, stuck in a problem. I have installed yii users and rights. It gives me error whenever I try to run `localhost/webapp/table` it gives an error which is `"Error 404 The system is unable to find the requested action "list"` , but when I try to run `localhost/webapp/table/index` it shows me the view of index action which is working fine. Here is my `config/main.php`

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.

return array(
     'theme' => 'bootstrap',
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'emergency response system',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),
'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => 'ext.bootstrap'),
    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
         'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
                'bootstrap.helpers.*',
                'bootstrap.widgets.*',
                'application.modules.user.models.*',
                'application.modules.user.components.*',
                'application.modules.rights.*',
                'application.modules.rights.components.*',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'ers',
                     'generatorPaths' => array(
                'bootstrap.gii', ),
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
            'user' => array(
            'tableUsers' => 'user',
            'tableProfiles' => 'profiles',
            'tableProfileFields' => 'profiles_fields',
                # encrypting method (php hash function)
                'hash' => 'md5',

                # send activation email
                'sendActivationMail' => true,

                # allow access for non-activated users
                'loginNotActiv' => false,

                # activate user on registration (only sendActivationMail = false)
                'activeAfterRegister' => false,

                # automatically login from registration
                'autoLogin' => true,

                # registration path
               'registrationUrl' => array('/user/registration'),

                # recovery password path
                'recoveryUrl' => array('/user/recovery'),

                # login form path
                'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),

                # page after login
                'returnUrl' => array('/user/profile'),

               # page after logout
               'returnLogoutUrl' => array('/user/login'),


    ),
             'rights'=>array(
             'install'=>true,
                 'superuserName'=>'Admin', // Name of the role with super user privileges. 
               'authenticatedName'=>'Authenticated',  // Name of the authenticated user role. 
               'userIdColumn'=>'id', // Name of the user id column in the database. 
               'userNameColumn'=>'username',  // Name of the user name column in the database. 
               'enableBizRule'=>true,  // Whether to enable authorization item business rules. 
               'enableBizRuleData'=>true,   // Whether to enable data for business rules. 
               'displayDescription'=>true,  // Whether to use item description instead of name. 
               'flashSuccessKey'=>'RightsSuccess', // Key to use for setting success flash messages. 
               'flashErrorKey'=>'RightsError', // Key to use for setting error flash messages. 
               'baseUrl'=>'/rights', // Base URL for Rights. Change if module is nested. 
               'layout'=>'rights.views.layouts.main',  // Layout to use for displaying Rights. 
               'appLayout'=>'application.views.layouts.main', // Application layout. 
               'cssFile'=>'rights.css', // Style sheet file to use for Rights. 
               'install'=>false,  // Whether to enable installer. 
               'debug'=>false, 
        ),
            ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(

        'user'=>array(
                    'class'=>'RWebUser',
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                    'loginUrl'=>array('/user/login'),
        ),
            'authManager'=>array(
                'class'=>'RDbAuthManager',
                'connectionID'=>'db',
                'defaultRoles'=>array('Authenticated', 'Guest'),

                'itemTable'=>'authitem',
                'itemChildTable'=>'authitemchild',
                'assignmentTable'=>'authassignment',
                'rightsTable'=>'rights',
        ),


        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.BsApi',),

        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
                     'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                 '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/list',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            ),
        ),


        // database settings are configured in database.php
//      'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=response_system',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),

            ),
        ),

    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),

);
```

and here is my model file

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "story".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'story':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $story
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property UserWriteStory[] $userWriteStories
 */
class Story extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Story the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'story';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('title, story', 'required'),
            array('title', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('story', 'length', 'max'=>1000),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, title, story', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'userWriteStories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserWriteStory', 'story_story_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'story' => 'Story',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
        $criteria->compare('story',$this->story,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

and this is my related controller.

```
<?php

class StoryController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Story;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Story']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Story'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Story']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Story'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Story');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Story('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Story']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Story'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Story the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Story::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Story $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='story-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your related controller

Comment: @scaisEdge i have pasted the related controller.

Comment: @scaisEdge i have updated with the related controller.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your main.php of config file, comment out this line:

```
<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/list
```

Comment: How did this answer get accepted if the code was not visible? I have edited it so that the XML tags are now visible.

Answer (score 0):

In Your  `config/main.php`  in your `ruoting /rewrite` rules you have assigned like  default action =  `list` but actionList is not present in yourController . Then when non action are setted in url Yii invoke list.php   instead of index.php  (error 404)

You need change this:

```
'<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/list',
```

Change this in this way

```
'<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
```

Or like suggest by @Usman Daby Khan  you can delete it, in this way the default behaviour fo Yii2 comeback to work.

Answer (score 0):

In UrlManager -> rules you can remove this line

```
'<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/list',
```

and set defaultAction property of the Controller:

```
class StoryController extends RController
{
      public $defaultAction = 'list';
```