# Yii: Video upload gets failed upon uploading

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am yiibie. What i am tying to do to upload videos, for that i am using `Uploadmiltifiles` extension and following this link `http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/uploadmultifiles`. I have followed every thing but when i upload a video file(.3gp file) i says `"testingvideo.3gp"` failed and upon submit it says `"Video file cannot be blank"` This is the code of my videoController which has the `actionupload() function`.

```
<?php

class VideoController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */

    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Video;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Video']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Video'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Video']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Video'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
 public function actionUpload()
{

        Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");

        $folder=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/';// folder for uploaded files
        $allowedExtensions = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov","mp4",);//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
        $sizeLimit = 100 * 1024 * 1024;// maximum file size in bytes
        $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
        $return = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

        $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME
        //$img = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

        echo $return;// it's array
}
    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Video');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Video('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Video']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Video'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Video the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Video::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }


    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Video $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='video-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of my Video view file(_form.php)

```
<?php
/* @var $this VideoController */
/* @var $model Video */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */
?>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'video-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<?php //echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id'); ?>
     <?php

  $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'name'=>'Video[user_id]',
  'data'=>CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'username'), //the whole available list
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
       'placeholder'=>' search User name?',
    //'options'=>$options, //the selected values
    //'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'style'=>'width:530px',
  ),
  ));
    ?> <br><br>
    <?php
 $this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
array(
        'id'=>'uploadFile',
        'config'=>array(
               'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('site/upload'),
               'allowedExtensions'=>array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov","mp4","txt","doc","pdf","xls","3gp","php","ini","avi","rar","zip","png"),//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
               'sizeLimit'=>1000*1024*1024,// maximum file size in bytes
               'minSizeLimit'=>1*1024,
               'auto'=>true,
               'multiple' => true,
               'onComplete'=>"js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ alert(fileName); }",
               'messages'=>array(
                                 'typeError'=>"{file} has invalid extension. Only {extensions} are allowed.",
                                'sizeError'=>"{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
                                'minSizeError'=>"{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
                                'emptyError'=>"{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
                                'onLeave'=>"The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
                               ),
               'showMessage'=>"js:function(message){ alert(message); }"
               )

               ));
?>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'filename',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'user_id'); ?>

    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

And this is the code of my `config/main.php`

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.

return array(
     'theme' => 'bootstrap',
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'emergency response system',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),
'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => 'ext.bootstrap'),
    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
         'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
                'bootstrap.helpers.*',
                'bootstrap.widgets.*',
                'application.modules.user.models.*',
                'application.modules.user.components.*',
                'application.modules.rights.*',
                'application.modules.rights.components.*',
                'application.extensions.EAjaxUpload.*',//this is for uploading of video
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'ers',
                     'generatorPaths' => array(
                'bootstrap.gii', ),
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
            'user' => array(
            'tableUsers' => 'user',
            'tableProfiles' => 'profiles',
            'tableProfileFields' => 'profiles_fields',
//                # encrypting method (php hash function)
//                'hash' => 'md5',
// 
//                # send activation email
//                'sendActivationMail' => true,
// 
//                # allow access for non-activated users
//                'loginNotActiv' => false,
// 
//                # activate user on registration (only sendActivationMail = false)
//                'activeAfterRegister' => false,
// 
//                # automatically login from registration
//                'autoLogin' => true,
// 
//                # registration path
//               'registrationUrl' => array('/user/registration'),
//
//                # recovery password path
//                'recoveryUrl' => array('/user/recovery'),
// 
//                # login form path
//                'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
// 
//                # page after login
//                'returnUrl' => array('/user/profile'),
// 
//               # page after logout
//               'returnLogoutUrl' => array('/user/login'),


    ),
             'rights'=>array(
             'install'=>true,
//                 'superuserName'=>'Admin', // Name of the role with super user privileges. 
//               'authenticatedName'=>'Authenticated',  // Name of the authenticated user role. 
//               'userIdColumn'=>'id', // Name of the user id column in the database. 
//               'userNameColumn'=>'username',  // Name of the user name column in the database. 
//               'enableBizRule'=>true,  // Whether to enable authorization item business rules. 
//               'enableBizRuleData'=>true,   // Whether to enable data for business rules. 
//               'displayDescription'=>true,  // Whether to use item description instead of name. 
//               'flashSuccessKey'=>'RightsSuccess', // Key to use for setting success flash messages. 
//               'flashErrorKey'=>'RightsError', // Key to use for setting error flash messages. 
//               'baseUrl'=>'/rights', // Base URL for Rights. Change if module is nested. 
//               'layout'=>'rights.views.layouts.main',  // Layout to use for displaying Rights. 
//               'appLayout'=>'application.views.layouts.main', // Application layout. 
//               'cssFile'=>'rights.css', // Style sheet file to use for Rights. 
//               'install'=>false,  // Whether to enable installer. 
//               'debug'=>false, 
        ),
            ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(

        'user'=>array(
                    'class'=>'RWebUser',
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                    'loginUrl'=>array('/user/login'),
        ),
            'authManager'=>array(
                'class'=>'RDbAuthManager',
                'connectionID'=>'db',
                'defaultRoles'=>array('Authenticated', 'Guest'),

//                'itemTable'=>'authitem',
//                'itemChildTable'=>'authitemchild',
//                'assignmentTable'=>'authassignment',
//                'rightsTable'=>'rights',
        ),


        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.BsApi',),

        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
                     'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
        //'<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/list',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            ),
        ),


        // database settings are configured in database.php
//      'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=response_system',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),

            ),
        ),

    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),

);
```

And this the model of video

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "video".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'video':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $filename
 * @property integer $user_id
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property User $user
 */
class Video extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Video the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'video';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('filename, user_id', 'required'),
            array('user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('filename', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, filename, user_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'filename' => 'Filename',
            'user_id' => 'User',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('filename',$this->filename,true);
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
Please help me with this, thank you.
```

Comment: Show your model Video please

Comment: @SiZE i have updated the question with video model.

Comment: How is big the file you want to upload?

Comment: it's just a 1mb file..

Comment: @scaisEdge any solution..??

Comment: I don't the extension you are using.  I don't understand how the data are send from the widget (_form, seem invoking `action...site/upload` but this i wrong because you use `video/upload`), and how are recived by actionUpload because i don't see param in function call or POST related info eventually passed by submit..  I don't understand the logic of the code...

Comment: can you please have a look of the link i have given in the question, that might help you in giving the solution.

Comment: or is there any other which i can use for uploading of videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the view file needs to be like this.

```
<?php
/* @var $this VideoController */
/* @var $model Video */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */
?>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'video-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<?php //echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id'); ?>
     <?php

  $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'name'=>'Video[user_id]',
  'data'=>CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'username'), //the whole available list
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
       'placeholder'=>' search User name?',
    //'options'=>$options, //the selected values
    //'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'style'=>'width:530px',
  ),
  ));
    ?> <br><br>
    <?php
 $this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
array(
        'id'=>'uploadFile',
        'config'=>array(
               'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('video/upload'),//add your controller name here
               'allowedExtensions'=>array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov","mp4","txt","doc","pdf","xls","3gp","php","ini","avi","rar","zip","png"),//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
               'sizeLimit'=>1000*1024*1024,// maximum file size in bytes
               'minSizeLimit'=>1*1024,
               'auto'=>true,
               'multiple' => true,
               'onComplete'=>"js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ alert(fileName); }",
               'messages'=>array(
                                 'typeError'=>"{file} has invalid extension. Only {extensions} are allowed.",
                                'sizeError'=>"{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
                                'minSizeError'=>"{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
                                'emptyError'=>"{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
                                'onLeave'=>"The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
                               ),
               'showMessage'=>"js:function(message){ alert(message); }"
               )

               ));
?>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'filename',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'user_id'); ?>

    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

and controller needs to be like this,

```
<?php

class VideoController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */

    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Video;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Video']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Video'];
                        Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");
        $folder=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/..video/';// folder for uploaded files
        $allowedExtensions = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov","mp4","txt","doc","pdf","xls","3gp","php","ini","avi","rar","zip","png");//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
        $sizeLimit = 100 * 1024 * 1024;// maximum file size in bytes
        $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
        $return = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

        $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME
        //$img = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

        echo $return;// it's array

            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
            }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Video']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Video'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Video');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Video('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Video']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Video'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
       public function actionUpload()
{

        Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");

        $folder=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/video/';// folder for uploaded files
        $allowedExtensions = array();//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
        $sizeLimit = 100 * 1024 * 1024;// maximum file size in bytes
        $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
        $return = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

        $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME
        //$img = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

        echo $return;// it's array
}

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Video the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Video::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }


    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Video $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='video-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your html form doesn't have the `enctype` attribute so `$_FILES` is empty. Try to add:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'video-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,

    'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),

)); ?>
```

Comment: @Kotas Mitsarakis still no success.

Comment: Comment out the EAjaxUpload widget to eliminate possible jQuery errors and make a var_dump($_FILES); to see if there are any posted files.

Comment: Also maybe you have to add actionUpload in access rules or rights (I don't have use rights before)?

Comment: well i found out the answer. 
firstly the line from the controller has to be like this $folder=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/..video/' and secondly i was giving the wrong controller in the view file which had to be like this 'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('video/upload'),
now upload anything you want.

Comment: Great! Can you make this an answer and post it as the solution?

Comment: ya sure, ill put an answer thanks @Kostas Mitsarakis for your support.

Comment: I upvoted already it but you are the only one that can accept an answer in a question you have posted.

Comment: @Kotas Mitsarakis is there any way i can use the upload function in the actioncreate()..??

Comment: In your actionCreate() add: echo $this->actionUpload();

Comment: can you please upload your answer here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788202/yii-how-to-use-actionupload-in-actioncreate

Comment: @Kotas Mitsarakis can you please help me with this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800640/yii-any-extension-to-implement-embedded-google-map

Comment: hi @Kotas Mitsarakis, can you please help me with this question..??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063773/yiiunable-to-get-the-picture-using-through