# Yii: how to use actionupload() in actioncreate()

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

i am yiibie and i am trying to use the `uploadaction()`  function in the `createaction()` function so that i can upload videos and can also manage videos. I am using `multiuploadfile` extension. I dont know how to merge the upload function into create function.
This is the code of my VideoController which has both the `actionUpload()` and `actioncreate()` function.

```
<?php

class VideoController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */

    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Video;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Video']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Video'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
            }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Video']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Video'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Video');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Video('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Video']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Video'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
       public function actionUpload()
{

        Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");

        $folder=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/video/';// folder for uploaded files
        $allowedExtensions = array("mp4","3gp");//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
        $sizeLimit = 100 * 1024 * 1024;// maximum file size in bytes
        $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
        $return = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

        $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME
        //$img = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

        echo $return;// it's array
}

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Video the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Video::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }


    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Video $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='video-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me with this, thank you.

Comment: In which way you want combine/merge the two function .. please expalin better

Comment: Where do you use actionUpload() returned result?

Comment: actually by using the upload function i am able to upload videos to my directory by ain't getting anything in my db nor in the managevideos/admin.. so i thought of using actionupload() in actionCreate(), wolud that be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `actionUpload()` in `actionCreate()` using `$this` but you have to check how you will use the actionUpload results depending on what you want:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Video;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['Video'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Video'];

        $upload_results = $this->actionUpload();
        //Do something with $upload_results here

        if ($model->save()) {
            //Or after model saving do related saving with $upload_results here
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id'=>$model->id));
        }
    }
    $this->render('create', array(
        'model'=>$model,
        //'upload_results '=>$upload_results ,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how the videos can come into the projectname/videos/admin, so that i can manage my videos here, edit them or delete them. Can you please update it in the above answer.