# Yii upon login show the username and logout button

Tags: yii

i want a logout button and the username in my header widget when the user logs into successfully. i have already created a header and a footer widget and dont want to create another one. i want the code by which i can get the username and logout button in the header. i am using yii rights and extensions too. please help me with this..!!
i looked for the answer and someone had posted this stuff. i dont know where and how to use it. and this is the link of that solution.

```
 <?php if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){?>
 <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/user    /registration">Sign up</a></li> 
<li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/user    /login">login</a></li> <?php }?> 
<?php if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){?>
 <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/user/logout">
(<?php echo Yii::app()->user->name ?>) &nbsp;logout</a></li>
```

and this is the link of that solution. [show logout button along with the name of user after successfull login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272633/show-logout-button-along-with-the-name-of-user-after-successfull-login)

```
                        <!--header.php-->
  <div class="header">
                             <div class="row logo">
                                 <div class="col-md-6">
                                     <br>
                                     <a href=''><p>ERS.com</p></a>
                                 </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-6">
                                      <br>
                                    <a href=''><p class='pull-    right'>SignUp</p></a>
                                    <a href='<?php echo     Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/site/login'><p class='pull-right'     style='margin-right: 12px'>LogIn</p></a>
                                 <?php  
   if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    echo Yii::app()->user->name;
    }
   ?>
                                  </div>
                             </div><!--row ending here-->
                             <div class="row navigation">
                                 <br>
                                 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">    <p>Home</p>        </a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">    <p>Ngo's</p>    </a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">    <p>Blogs</p>    </a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">    <p>Stories</p>    </a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">    <p>Videos</p>    </a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">    <p>Gallery</p>    </a></li>
                    </ul>
                                     <br>
                                     </div>
                             </div><!--row ending here-->
                             <?php  
   if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    echo Yii::app()->user->name;
    }
 ?>
                         </div> <!--header ending here-->


</div>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this widget in your layout

```
<body>

  <div class="container" id="page">

  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></div>
  </div><!-- header -->

<div id="mainmenu">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    )); ?>
</div><!-- mainmenu -->
<?php if(isset($this->breadcrumbs)):?>
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
        'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
    )); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->
<?php endif?>

<?php echo $content; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="footer">
    Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> by my copy... - All Rights Reserved.<br/>
    <?php echo Yii::powered(); ?>
</div><!-- footer -->
```

the last two are what you are looking for ...

And for your last request i hope this is what you are looking for

```
<?php  
   if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
       echo  "<a href='" .  Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . 
       "/site/login'><p class='pull-right' style='margin-right: 12px'>LogIn</p></a>";
    }

    ........

    .....
   if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
       echo  Yii::app()->user->name .  " <a href='" .  
            Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . 
             "/site/logout'><p class='pull-right' style='margin-right: 12px'>Logout</p></a>";
    }
```

?>

Comment: where to exactly paste this code, can u give me the path.

Comment: You should use this code inside protected/view/layout/main.php

Comment: Thanks @SalikAsad.You can also rate as useful using the up arrow  top left of the answer...

Comment: look bro, i am logging in via webapp/site/login and upon login from here i want my header login button to logout and show me the username. like the code below as it is working fine for displaying username.
<?php  
   if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    echo Yii::app()->user->name;
   }
now i want my header Login button to logout upon login from site/login.
i have edited the question with my header.php

Comment: i want my Login button to change to Logout once i have logged into via webapp/site/login.
and then the logout button to login when i logout of the webapp.

Comment: okay mate let me have a look.. better if you edit that code in my header which i have posted in my question.

Comment: You must learn not ask to other for  work..Is for this i post suggestion and not solution.. Solution don't educate.. a good programmer...

Comment: yes i know, i was getting lazy, its deep night in here and im feeling sleepy.
but man you are really good with these things.

Comment: hi @scaisEdge as you answered to this question, i need to know one thing. As it gives me the logged in user name in the header but i want to change the style the username is represented in the header. For now it is in black color, i want it to be in white italic, how to change it's style..!!

Comment: Now I'm busy but tomorrow morning i can evaluate this question... If i forgotten comment me for remember

Comment: ok. please post a question with the related code and comment me the question url..

Comment: @scaisEdhe here you go..!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700507/yii-change-the-style-of-the-username-in-header-upon-login

Comment: @scaisEdhe can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754332/yii-video-upload-gets-failed-upon-uploading

Comment: can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980542/yii-not-getting-images-from-database-using-cdbcriteria