# Yii: change the style of the username in header upon login

Tags: php, css, yii

i am a yiibie. i want to change the style of the username in the header upon login. Currently it is shown in black color, and i want it to be italic white. Down there is the code of my header, please help me with this, thankyou.

```
<div class="header">
     <div class="row logo">
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <br>
             <a href='<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/emergency_response'><p>ERS.com</p></a>
         </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <br>
            <a href=''><p class='pull-right'>SignUp</p></a>
            <!--to show the username and logout button in the header upon login-->
               <?php  
                     if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
                             echo "<a href='".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/user/login'>
                                                <p class='pull-right' style='margin-right: 12px'>LogIn</p>
                                        </a>";
                        }
                        if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
                             echo  Yii::app()->user->name . " <a href='".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . "/user/logout' style='color:blue';>
                                    <p class='pull-right' style='margin-right: 12px'>Logout</p>
                                </a>";
                        }
                        ?>
          </div>
     </div><!--row ending here-->
     <div class="row navigation">
         <br>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><p>Home</p></a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><p>Ngo's</p></a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><p>Blogs</p></a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><p>Stories</p></a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><p>Videos</p></a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><p>Gallery</p></a></li>
                            </ul>
         <br>
       </div>
        </div><!--row ending here-->
</div> <!--header ending here-->
<!-- <div class="row">
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    )); ?>
</div>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  this

```
    if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
           echo  '<span style="color: white; font-style: italic;">'. Yii::app()->user->name .  "</span> <a href='" .  
                Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . 
                 "/site/logout' ><p class='pull-right' style='margin-right: 12px'>Logout</p></a>";
        }
```

Comment: Thank mate.. good work... Just a curiosity.. what time is it in you country now...?

Comment: please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709492/property-tablename-title-is-not-defined

Comment: can you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800640/yii-any-extension-to-implement-embedded-google-map