# Yii: error 404, your request is invalid upon deletion

Tags: php, yii

what i am doing is that when the admin login via webapp/user/login it has certain things to control. when ever i want to delete any data from there like, if i want to delete a picture of an event, it gives me an error "Error 400 Your request is invalid". what colud be the problem. i have posted the controller code of event table.

```
<?php

class EventController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Event;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Event']))
        {
                     $rnd = rand(0,9999);  // generate random number between 0-9999
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Event'];
                         $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
            $model->image = $fileName;
            if($model->save())
                             {
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/'.$fileName);  // image will uplode to rootDirectory/event/
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Event']))
        {
                    $_POST['Event']['image'] = $model->image;
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Event'];
                        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

            if($model->save())
                            {
                if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                {
                 $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../event/'.$model->image);
                }
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Event');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Event('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Event']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Event'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Event the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Event::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Event $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='event-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How you invoke the request for deletion...?

Comment: isn't that already in the actiondelete() function..??

Comment: if not then please guide me how to do this.

Comment: You call the delete action from a view , a menu link or a button. I need the code a must see how you call the delete action

Comment: can you tell me the exact file you need, path to that directory..??

Comment: Where you click delete... i need this view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is related to the http  method you use for call. Probably you use a get method but you need a post method

You should have somethings like this

```
array('label'=>'Delete', 'url'=>'#',
   'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('event/delete','id'=>$model->id),
  'confirm'=>('Are you sure to delete this item?'), 
 'method' =>'post')),
```

check if you have method  =  post

deleteAction  only allow deletion via POST request

Comment: sorry @scaisEdge there was some problem with my internet, can you please tell me the path where this file is located so that i can have a look.

Comment: If you don't know where you call the command how can i know it? You call the delete ? where ? show the code where you call tthe delete?

Comment: sorry mate, i know i keep on asking foolish questions. Actually im new to this so i have no much idea about things.
And for the question, i dont know how i t started working by itself..!!
but thanks mate, u are very helpful, again apologies.

Comment: tell me how you did call the action_Delete so I can understand how you generated the error ..Nothings happen by itself....

Comment: i just generated the models and controller again and it worked

Comment: yes i dont know how but it is working now, and was having issues with yii user and rights css it also got solved but i dont know how..!!
all i used was gii