# Yii: Not getting images from database using CDbCriteria

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie.I am trying to get images from my database table named `event` and i am using `CDbCriteria`. I have a little bit knowledge of how using it but right now i am unable to retrieve the images from my database, might be i am writing my code wrong or mixing few things. By using this code i am not getting any error, i am not just getting the image, please help me with this thing, thank you.

```
<?php
 $Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->limit = 4;
$Criteria->order = "id DESC";
$Criteria->select = "id, image";
$Events = Event::model()->findAll($Criteria);
  ?>
<div class="row">
<h3>Events</h3>
<?php
foreach ( (array)$Events as $Event)
{
   echo "
      <div class='col-md-3'>
         <div class='thumbnail'>
            <img src='<? php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>$Event->image' >
            <div class='caption'>
               <a href='join.php'><button class='btn btn-primary center-block'>Join</button></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   ";
}
?>
<a href="events.php"> <p class="view">View all</p></a>

</div><!--row ending here-->
```

Comment: seems you want only the first 4 (id, image) orber by id DESC, ok?

Comment: show you Event model / data schema please

Comment: yes @scasEdge this is what i want. i just want the image id and the image(not image name), i tried one thing which is when i remove the single quotes from this line <img src='<?php echo YII::app()->request->baseUrl;?>$Event->image'>, it gives me an output like this request->baseUrl;?>(name of image)>

Comment: where as my scheme has only two objects in it id and image..!!

Comment: The image is a link  / filename of the image?

Comment: @scaisEdge done with it, thanks to Glapa, he will update the answer soon..!!
and thanks to you as well for responding.

Comment: @scaisEdge can you please have a llok at this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051729/yii-how-to-get-multiple-data-from-db

Answer (score 0):

First and most obvious bug is in loop. Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
foreach ( (array)$Events as $Event)
{
   echo "
      <div class='col-md-3'>
         <div class='thumbnail'>
            <img src="'.Yii::app()->request->baseurl.'/img folder path/'.$Event->image.'">                <div class='caption'>
               <a href='join.php'><button class='btn btn-primary center-block'>Join</button></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   ";
}
?>
```

It should be enough to make your code work. The way you were concatenating strings (by using  inside outer one) is incorrect. In PHP strings are concatenated by `.` sing.

Comment: still getting nothing.

Comment: Ok then tell me, does `$Event->image` contains filename of this image on server or is it image itself?

Comment: it is just an image itself stored in my db

Comment: Do you know what is extension of this file? (jpg, gif, png?)

Comment: sorry mate, it still didn't worked, all the problem i guess i just with the <img src=""> line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96457/discussion-between-glapa-and-salik-asad).

Comment: Hi @Glapa, can you please help me with this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051729/yii-how-to-get-multiple-data-from-db

Comment: Hi @Glapa, need your help, can you please have a look at this..??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063773/yiiunable-to-get-the-picture-using-through