# Yii: How to get multiple data from db

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie. I am trying to get data from database onto the front page. The table name is `story` and i want to get the title and story from the table. For that i have made a `allstory.php` file in my view file and created a function of `allstory()` in my `storycontroller`.
This is the code for my controller.

```
<?php

class StoryController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
public function actionAllstory() //This has been added to view all the stories on the  stories page
    {
               $this->layout='main';
        $this->render('allstory');
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Story;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Story']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Story'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Story']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Story'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Story');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Story('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Story']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Story'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Story the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Story::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Story $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='story-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my allstory.php of view file

```
 <div class="content">
                                     <div class="banner">
                                         <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/story-banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                                         </div><!--banner ending here--><br>
                                         <div class="story-content">


                                              <div class="row">
                                                 <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 vol-stories">
                                                     <div class="media">
                                        <div class="media-left">
                                            <a href="user-profile.php">
                                                <?php $modelnew=$model->story;
                                                foreach($modelnew as $test)
                                                {
                                                ?>
                                              <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/media.jpg">
                                          </a>
                                       </div>
                                        <div class="media-body"><strong><?php echo $test->user->username;?></strong> <!--username will come here-->

                                    <h4 class="media-heading"><strong><br><br><?php echo $test->title?></strong></h4><!--title will come here-->
                                       <p><?php echo $test->story?></p><!--story will come here-->
                                        <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>      
                                        </div>


                                              </div><!--Media ending here--> 
                                                 </div>
                                             </div><!--row ending here--><br>

                                             <hr>
                                             <div class="write-story">
                                                 <div class="row">
                                                     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><br>
                                                         <form>
                                                             <strong>Title:</strong><textarea class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
                                                         </form>
                                                     </div>
                                                 </div><!--row ending here-->
                                                  <div class="row">
                                                     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><br>
                                                         <form>
                                                             <strong>Story:</strong><textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                                                         </form>
                                                     </div>
                                                 </div><!--row ending here-->
                                                 <div class="row">
                                                  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><br>
                                                 <button class="btn btn-primary">Share</button>

                                                 </div>
                                                     </div><br>
                                                 </div><!--write-story ending here-->



</div><!--content ending here-->


                           </div><!--container ending here-->
```

This is the story model

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "story".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'story':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $story
 * @property integer $user_id
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property User $user
 */
class Story extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Story the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'story';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('title, story, user_id', 'required'),
            array('user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('title', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('story', 'length', 'max'=>1000),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, title, story, user_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'story' => 'Story',
            'user_id' => 'User',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
        $criteria->compare('story',$this->story,true);
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

This is the model for profile

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "profiles".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'profiles':
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property string $lastname
 * @property string $firstname
 * @property string $picture
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property User $user
 */
class Profiles extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Profiles the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'profiles';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('lastname, firstname', 'length', 'max'=>50),
            array('picture', 'length', 'max'=>500),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('user_id, lastname, firstname, picture', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'user_id' => 'User',
            'lastname' => 'Lastname',
            'firstname' => 'Firstname',
            'picture' => 'Picture',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
        $criteria->compare('lastname',$this->lastname,true);
        $criteria->compare('firstname',$this->firstname,true);
        $criteria->compare('picture',$this->picture,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

And this is the model for user

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'user':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $gender
 * @property string $activkey
 * @property string $create_at
 * @property string $lastvisit_at
 * @property integer $superuser
 * @property integer $status
 * @property string $salt
 * @property integer $requires_new_password
 * @property integer $login_attempts
 * @property integer $login_time
 * @property string $login_ip
 * @property string $activation_key
 * @property string $validation_key
 * @property string $create_time
 * @property string $update_time
 * @property string $reset_token
 * @property string $image
 * @property string $address
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property UserJoinEvent[] $userJoinEvents
 * @property UserRateReviewNgo[] $userRateReviewNgos
 * @property UserUploadVideo[] $userUploadVideos
 * @property UserWriteStory[] $userWriteStories
 * @property VolunteerForm[] $volunteerForms
 */
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return User the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('superuser, status, requires_new_password, login_attempts, login_time', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('username, login_ip, address', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            array('password, email, activkey, activation_key', 'length', 'max'=>120),
            array('gender', 'length', 'max'=>1),
            array('salt, validation_key', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('reset_token', 'length', 'max'=>250),
            array('image', 'length', 'max'=>450),
            array('create_at, lastvisit_at, create_time, update_time', 'safe'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, username, password, email, gender, activkey, create_at, lastvisit_at, superuser, status, salt, requires_new_password, login_attempts, login_time, login_ip, activation_key, validation_key, create_time, update_time, reset_token, image, address', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
               array('image', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
                    //array('title, image', 'length', 'max'=>255, 'on'=>'insert,update'),
                    );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'userJoinEvents' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserJoinEvent', 'User_user_id'),
            'userRateReviewNgos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserRateReviewNgo', 'User_user_id'),
            'userUploadVideos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserUploadVideo', 'User_user_id'),
            'userWriteStories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserWriteStory', 'User_user_id'),
            'volunteerForms' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'VolunteerForm', 'User_user_id'),
                        //'profile' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'profile', 'id','through'=>'user'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'gender' => 'Gender',
            'activkey' => 'Activkey',
            'create_at' => 'Create At',
            'lastvisit_at' => 'Lastvisit At',
            'superuser' => 'Superuser',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'salt' => 'Salt',
            'requires_new_password' => 'Requires New Password',
            'login_attempts' => 'Login Attempts',
            'login_time' => 'Login Time',
            'login_ip' => 'Login Ip',
            'activation_key' => 'Activation Key',
            'validation_key' => 'Validation Key',
            'create_time' => 'Create Time',
            'update_time' => 'Update Time',
            'reset_token' => 'Reset Token',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'address' => 'Address',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);
        $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
        $criteria->compare('gender',$this->gender,true);
        $criteria->compare('activkey',$this->activkey,true);
        $criteria->compare('create_at',$this->create_at,true);
        $criteria->compare('lastvisit_at',$this->lastvisit_at,true);
        $criteria->compare('superuser',$this->superuser);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
        $criteria->compare('salt',$this->salt,true);
        $criteria->compare('requires_new_password',$this->requires_new_password);
        $criteria->compare('login_attempts',$this->login_attempts);
        $criteria->compare('login_time',$this->login_time);
        $criteria->compare('login_ip',$this->login_ip,true);
        $criteria->compare('activation_key',$this->activation_key,true);
        $criteria->compare('validation_key',$this->validation_key,true);
        $criteria->compare('create_time',$this->create_time,true);
        $criteria->compare('update_time',$this->update_time,true);
        $criteria->compare('reset_token',$this->reset_token,true);
        $criteria->compare('image',$this->image,true);
        $criteria->compare('address',$this->address,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

I am unable to get any result as i don't have idea I am doing it right or wrong. As i am using this code it also gives me an error which is `Undefined variable: model`

Comment: You want a single story or all the stories in the table?

Comment: i want stories against the id, i mean when i write id=1 in the url it should give me the story of that id.

Comment: But you are talking about allstory().. Then you want code for allStory($id)?

Comment: Sorry mate, i was not clear about my task, i want to show all the stories which are in my story table.

Comment: @scaisEdge did you found any solution to this...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have

```
 class StoryController extends RController
```

why you extend RController and not simply Controller?

then for the controller if you want a single the story by id you need adn action like this

```
public function actionSingleStory($id) //This has been added to view a single story 
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    $this->layout='main';
    $this->render('singlestory', array('model'=>$model));
}
```

and a simplified view (singlestory.php) like this (I assume you have the field $model->story_title amd $model->story_text

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="banner">
         <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/story-banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div><!--banner ending here--><br>
    <div class="story-content">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 vol-stories">
                 <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="user-profile.php">
                            <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/media.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body"><strong><?php echo $test->user->username;?></strong> <!--username will come here-->
                        <h4 class="media-heading"><strong><br><br><?php echo $model->story_title?></strong></h4><!--title will come here-->
                        <p><?php echo $model->story_text?></p><!--story will come here-->
                     </div>
                </div><!--Media ending here--> 
            </div>
        </div><!--row ending here-->
    </div><!--content ending here-->
</div><!--container ending here-->
```

if you want all story

```
public function actionAllstory() //This has been added to view all the stories on the  stories page
{

     $allmodels =  Story::model()->findAll();
     $this->layout='main';
     $this->render('allstory', array('allmodels' => $allmodels));
}
```

the in the view (a simplified  allstory.php )

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="banner">
         <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/story-banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div><!--banner ending here--><br>
    <div class="story-content">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 vol-stories">
                 <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="user-profile.php">
                            <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/media.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                        foreach($allmodels as $model){
                            echo "<h4 class='media-heading'><strong>" . $model->story_title ."</strong></h4>" ; //<!--title will come here-->
                            echo "<p>" .  $model->story_text . "</p>" ; // <!--story will come here-->
                        }
                    ?>
                </div><!--Media ending here--> 
            </div>
        </div><!--row ending here-->
    </div><!--content ending here-->
</div><!--container ending here-->
```

Comment: thanks mate this worked fine, i am able to get username, title and story all, but unable to get the picture. The line for the code is <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->profile->picture;?>">
This gives me an error "Property "Story.profile" is not defined. " What could be he possible issue?

Comment: Is a problem related to your $model, Which model is involved? show this model please?

Comment: The story model is involved in this, i have updated my question with the story model. i think there will be something to add in the relation function but dont know what to write.

Comment: do you have a sloution for my question?

Comment: i am waiting for your answer, as i am not getting anything helping material for this.

Comment: Looking at your models i don't see relation  between user and profile. (I see only relation from profile and user) show also your user model. Because if you want get the profile related to an user you need a relation (has one) from User and the Profile

Comment: For the profile image  sub question post  a proper question, I may have found a solution