# yii:Unable to get the picture using "through"

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie, and i am stuck in a problem. I have made a file named `ngopage.php` in my view file and i am able to get the data from my `Ngo` table but I am unable to get the `Picture` of the user who is writing any comment for an `ngo` against a specific id of an `ngo`. The picture of the user is in the `profile` table and the reviews are coming from the `userRateReviewNgos` table. I am also able to get the reviews but not getting the picture of the user. I tried the `through` method in the `relation function` of the `userRateReviewNgos` model which gives an exception `Property "CBelongsToRelation.through" is not defined.` Please help me with this. thank you. 
This is the code for my `UserRateReviewNgos model`

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user_rate_review_ngo".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'user_rate_review_ngo':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $rate
 * @property string $review
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property integer $ngo_id
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Ngo $ngo
 * @property User $user
 */
class UserRateReviewNgo extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return UserRateReviewNgo the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_rate_review_ngo';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('rate, review, user_id, ngo_id', 'required'),
            array('rate, user_id, ngo_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('review', 'length', 'max'=>500),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, rate, review, user_id, ngo_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'ngo' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Ngo', 'ngo_id'),
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
'profile' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'profile', 'id','through'=>'user'),
                    );// here i have user the through method for getting picture form profile table
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'rate' => 'Rate',
            'review' => 'Review',
            'user_id' => 'User',
            'ngo_id' => 'Ngo',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('rate',$this->rate);
        $criteria->compare('review',$this->review,true);
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
        $criteria->compare('ngo_id',$this->ngo_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

This is the ngopage.php from view file

```
<div class="profile">
                                             <div class="row" style="background-color:">
                                                 <div class="col-md-4">
                                                     <img src="<?php echo YII::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image;?>" class="img-responsive"><br>
                                                 </div>
                                                 <div class="col-md-4">
                                                     <h2 class="profile-name" style="color:white;"><?php echo $model->ngo_name;?></h2>
                                                     <div class="rating">
                                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star 2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star 2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star 2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star 2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star 2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                     </div><!--rating ending here-->
                                                     <h3>Owner:</h3>
                                                     <p>Mr. Asad Abdul Jabbar</p>
                                                      <h3>Address:</h3>
                                                     <address>

                                               <p>  <?php echo $model->address;?><br></p>

                                          </address>
                                                      <h3>Requirements:</h3>
                                                      <p>-Volunteers required for refugees settlement in Kashmir<br>-Cash for food and water of refugees<br>-Donations can be transferred via online banking, AC no.<em>12345</em></p>
                                                     <h3>Write Review</h3>
                                                     <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="3" cols="4" name="requirements" value=""></textarea><br>
                                                     <button class="btn btn-primary">Share</button>
                                                 </div>
                                                 </div><!--row ending here--><br>


                                          </div><!--profile ending here--><br>

                                          <div class="story-content" style="background-color:white;">
                                             <div class="row">
                                                 <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 vol-stories">
                                                     <div class="media">
                                        <div class="media-left">
                                            <a href="user-profile.php">
                                                <?php $modelnew=$model->userRateReviewNgos; 
                                                foreach($modelnew as $new)
                                                {
                                               ?>

                                              <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo YII::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $new->profile->picture;?>">
                                          </a>
                                       </div>
                                        <div class="media-body"><strong><?php echo $new->user->username; ?></strong>
                                            <p style="color:black;"><?php echo $new->review;?></p>
                                          <?php   }
                                                ?>
                                              </div>
                                                         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</button>
                                                         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>


                                              </div><!--Media ending here--> 

                                                 </div>
                                             </div><!--row ending here--><hr class="half">

                                           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this i think you should use  a has one relation

```
'profile' => array(self::HAS_ONE,    'Profile', 'user_id'),
```

Comment: This may be useful for your Profile

Comment: i tried for your answer,  have pasted the line in the relation function of the UserRateReviewNgo model but not getting the image.

Comment: no there is no error, this just does't make any effect..!!

Comment: Well then the problem in not more related to the accessing method but I think could related  to the path src  of your image.( check for the correct path and filename. ) or the value of the relation key inside the HAS_ONE relation.  try change the user_id, with id

Comment: Don't know what is going out with it, the path and file name are correct. Well thanks for your help, please share if you find a solution to this..!!